# Validation for Navigation Properties in MVC (4) and EF (4)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, validation, asp.net-mvc-4

I created a model with EF and then created a controller and view in MVC.
The model type `A` has a Navigation Property to type `B`. So when I create `A` I want to select a `B`.

The MVC wizard to create the controller and view only created fields for Scalar Properties. So I went and changed my create action on `A` to:

```
public ActionResult Create() //Create action for A
{
    List<B> b = db.B.ToList(); //db is my DataContext

    ViewData["B"] = companies.Select(option => new SelectListItem
                    {
                        Text = (option.Name.ToString()),
                        Value = (option.Id.ToString())
                    });
    return View();
}
```

And added to my view:

```
<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.B)
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.B,  (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewData["B"], "---- Select B ----")
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.B)
</div>
```

All is good so far and I get the HTML

```
<select class="valid" id="B" name="B">
    <option value="">---- Select B ----</option>
    <option selected="selected" value="1">TestB</option>
</select>
```

However when I submit I get the error:

```
The value '1' is invalid.
```

Having not written any validation it must have been auto-generated somewhere. How do I correct it to check the values against the ViewData["B"] collection ID's?

Comment: use visual studio breakpoints and see where you are getting this error

Comment: I can't :(
The Create Post action test ModelState.IsValid so its before I can set the breakpoint.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the value of your dropdown list is `Id` - but the property is a `B`.

You should bind to the FK of your navigation property instead.  I'm not sure of your model (if this doesn't help you should post it)

```
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.BId,  (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewData["B"], "---- Select B ----")
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.BId)
</div>
```

Note I've changed `model.B` to `model.BId`

Comment: Value must be a string (it gets put into HTML after all). If I use option.ToString() then I get the error: System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.Company_0666B8A654DC2C6F1C8E3E01AD765AF62C7D70E1D339E44C8F4F12131B24DBB9
(Company is the B in my scenario).

"It might be better though, to bind to the FK property instead of your navigation item, then use Id." Can you point to a resource on this or explain it? Thanks

Comment: Hmmmm. I guess I will have to put the FK ID in to my own partial definition of A. So I guess this would validate the FK as just a scalar property. This will solve my problem. I was just hoping there would be some sugar to validate the drop downs values back to actual ID to ensure FK integrity.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

So I found a (verbose) way to have my cake and eat it too without having to put in extra fields for FK id's

I changed my POST create action to the FormCollection format.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(FormCollection collection) //POST create for A
{
    A a = new A();

    a.Name = collection["Name"];
    a.Description = collection["Description"];

    try
    {
        int bId = Int32.Parse(collection["B"]);
        a.B = db.B.First(option => option.Id == bId);
        ValidateModel(a);
    }
    catch
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError("B", new Exception("bId does not match an existing B"));
    }

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.A.Add(a);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    //Failed
    //Go back to create form
    List<B> blist = db.B.ToList();

    ViewData["B"] = blist.Select(option => new SelectListItem
    {
        Text = (option.Name.ToString()),
        Value = (option.Id.ToString())
    });

    return View(a);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another method, without adding extra field (BId on class A), or reading model fields from FormCollection, would be to bind model.b.Id directly in the view.

```
<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.B)
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.B.Id,  (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewData["B"], "---- Select B ----")
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.B)
</div>
```

This binding binds Id to the navigation property B of A. To bind Name property, we need to read B from database context once.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(A a){
   B b = db.Bs.Find(a.B.Id);
   a.B = b;
   db.As.Add(a);
   db.SaveChanges();
}
```